# ElasticSearch in Docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I'm running an elasticsearch instance within Docker for a development environment and I am getting this error which I do not know how to fix:

> "type": "server", "timestamp": "2023-11-21T10:51:38,428Z", "level":
> "ERROR", "component": "o.e.x.d.l.DeprecationIndexingComponent",
> "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "ff696add001b",
> "message": "Bulk write of 1 deprecation logs failed:
> autoGeneratedTimestamp should not be set externally", "cluster.uuid":
> "73p5mXnQSJGqg_BMN22XQw", "node.id": "X40M5KsQRrGOAxlEAvk2Rg"

elasticsearch is specified within the Docker file as follows:

```
  elasticsearch:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.17.6
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
```

Could anyone advise me how to fix the issue please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key part of the message is `autoGeneratedTimestamp should not be set externally`. This suggests that there is an issue with how timestamps are being handled for deprecation logs.

If you have any custom code or integrations running with Elasticsearch, especially anything that writes to the deprecation logs or modifies logging behavior, review it to ensure it's not setting the `autoGeneratedTimestamp`.

Also, ensure that your Elasticsearch configuration does not contain any settings that might be incorrectly setting timestamps for logs. Sometimes custom configurations or plugins might interfere with the default logging mechanisms.

You can also check your logging configuration in Elasticsearch. It's possible that the format or settings of the logs are causing issues with how the timestamps are generated or interpreted.

Comment: My solution was actually to go to an older version of ElasticSearch, but this sent me in the right direction